# Associate one schema with another

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have my user schema:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  active: { type: Boolean, default: false }
});
```

I want to create a leave status schema. Data will be given by only one user about all leave status. I want to associate each one of the leave status to there respective user schema id.  I tried leave status schema as the following:

```
const leaveSchema = new Schema({
  leave: [
    {
      email: { type: String, required: true },
      month: { type: String, required: true },
      year: { type: Number, required: true },
      earnedleave: { type: Number },
      sickleave: { type: Number },
      festivalleave: { type: Number },
      compoff: { type: Number }
    }
  ]
});
```

How can i associate my emailid  with userschema. Can it be possible? If so, how can i tweak it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't need to associate the schema to get `leave` based on `user`, You can use aggregation for that,

```
db.user.aggregate([
    ...
    {$lookup: {from: "leave", localField: "email", foreignField: "leave.email", as: "leaves"}},
    ...
]);
```

Still, If you like to associate two collection, You have to use `ref` using `ObjectId`

```
const leaveSchema = new Schema({
  leave: [
    {
      user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user' }, //Your model name as reference
      email: { type: String, required: true },
      month: { type: String, required: true },
      year: { type: Number, required: true },
      earnedleave: { type: Number },
      sickleave: { type: Number },
      festivalleave: { type: Number },
      compoff: { type: Number }
    }
  ]
});
```